# How can I make a C# script execute in a certain order?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, connection

I have a script conflict that checks if there is network connection and the version of the game (if it's up to date); but it's skipping those conditions and loading the game directly.

How do I make the script follow this pattern?:

1. Check if there is internet connection
2. Check the version of the game
3. Only load the game if there is an internet connection and the version of the game is current

You'll notice there are some loading function who repeat themselves; I'm not sure which ones to apply.

### CheckNetwork.cs

```
public Text AlertText;
public GameObject alert;
public string URL = "";
public string CurrentVersion;
string latestVersion;
public GameObject newVersionAvailable;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadTxtData(URL));
}

void Awake()
{
    if (Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable)
    {
        alert.SetActive(true);
        AlertText.text = "Sorry, you have to enable your conection to play this game";
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            Application.Quit();
    }
    else
    {
        alert.SetActive(false);
        CheckVersion();
    }
}

public void CheckVersion()
{
    if(CurrentVersion != latestVersion)
    {
        newVersionAvailable.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        newVersionAvailable.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private IEnumerator LoadTxtData(string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    latestVersion = www.ToString();
    CheckVersion();
}

public void OpenURL(string url)
{
    Application.OpenURL(url);
}
```

### Loading.cs

```
private Image progressBar;

private void Start()
{
    Invoke("LoadAsyncOperation", 3f);
    StartCoroutine(LoadAsyncOperation());
}

public IEnumerator LoadAsyncOperation()
{
    AsyncOperation gameLevel = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
    while (gameLevel.progress < 1)
    {
        progressBar.fillAmount = gameLevel.progress;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

### Loading2.cs

```
public GameObject loadingScreenObj;
public Slider slider;

AsyncOperation async;

public void StartGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
}

public void LoadScreen(int LVL)
{
    //StartCoroutine(loadingScreen());
}

IEnumerator LoadingScreen(int lvl)
{
    loadingScreenObj.SetActive(true);
    async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(lvl);
    async.allowSceneActivation = false;

    while (async.isDone == false)
    {
        slider.value = async.progress;
        if (async.progress == 0.9f)
        {
            slider.value = 1f;
            async.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

### SplashScrean.cs

```
void Start()
{
    Invoke("loadMenuLevel", 3f);
    Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
}

void loadMenuLevel()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("gameplay");
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
    {
        loadMenuLevel();
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: in genral https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html didn't read all your code so far. Could you reduce it a bit to the core problem? you should probably rather have one central manager script that follows that order and just uses the other scripts to do its job

Comment: thanks but it's not about the central manager If you read the script you'll notice there are some incompatibility conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you call the `Invoke("loadMenuLevel", 3f);` method in the `Start()` method in the `SplashScrean.cs` script.

`Start()` is invoked very soon after a `MonoBehaviour` is attached to an object. Ostensibly, you have it attached to a `GameObject` in the scene. All of these are being hit at once.

You also have it as invokable via left mouse click in the same script's `Update()` method:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
{
    loadMenuLevel();
}
```

I would add `bools` to each of the loading scripts that are set to `true` when each task completes. Then, in `SplashScrean.cs`, change the above condition to load the level automatically if all three are complete. Or, keep the key press condition and add the `bools`.

```
if (Application.internetReachability != NetworkReachability.NotReachable 
    && loadScriptComplete && isCurrentVersion && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
{
    loadMenuLevel();
}
```

Now, if you also need the Loading `MonoBehaviours` to wait to execute their loading logic too, then consider adding `Update()` logic to them that checks the flag you set in `CheckNetwork.cs`.

```
//For example. Instead of this
private void Start()
{
    Invoke("LoadAsyncOperation", 3f);
    StartCoroutine(LoadAsyncOperation());
}

//Do this
private void Update()
{
   //Note that we only need to check if it is a CurrentVersion, as if that is true, then we definitely have internet access.
   if(CheckNetwork.IsCurrentVersion) {
      Invoke("LoadAsyncOperation", 3f);
      StartCoroutine(LoadAsyncOperation());
   }
}
```

**Edits/Additional Notes As I notice:**

`CheckNetwork.cs` references `CheckVersion();` in the `else` clause. That seems pointless. It is impossible for `LoadTxtData()` to have set the logic that `CheckVersion()` relies on in that time frame. A sort of race condition, if you will. Plus, you handle that check in `LoadTxtData()` anyways, so I would just do that there.

Comment: Why would you want a key click here

Comment: I would ask him. It's his code. But my best guess is that he has the splash screen load along with menu scene, and allows the person to press "Continue". A lot of games have a "Continue" button at the end of intro loads before continuing to the initial menu selection. The same before any load screen, like when loading into a level. To prevent people who aren't ready from being jettisoned into an active game situation.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but this isn't quite accurate: `Start() is invoked the moment a MonoBehaviour is attached to an object.`. [Start is called before the first frame update only if the script instance is enabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html). And: `For objects added to the scene, the Start function will be called on all scripts before Update, etc are called for any of them. Naturally, this cannot be enforced when an object is instantiated during gameplay.` Great answer otherwise, upvoted!

Comment: Thanks for the correction and edits. Edited it to say "very soon after" instead of "the moment".

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a complete copy-pastable code here (mainy because I don't fully understand yet how all your scripts are connected between each other) but I see you are already using [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

I would as mentioned before **use one central manager** to handle all those things.

I will only give you a general pseudo-code here and hope you find your way frome here

```
public class LoadManager
{
    public CheckNetwork check;
    public Loading loading;
    public Loading2 loading2;
    public SplashScrean splashScreen;

    // suprise: a not well documented fact 
    // you can simply make the Start method an IEnumerator (Coroutine)
    // so you can directly wait for anything you want
    private void IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // Next suprise: You can simply yield other IEnumerators
        // that makes them execute and at the same time waits until they are finished
        // so all methods that you want to wait for from here
        // should be IEnumerators

        // as said this is only an example 
        // you could directly within that single
        // Coroutine do your complete download and check routine together
        yield return check.CheckPermissions();
        if(!check.isReachable)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        // same for chekcing the version
        yield return check.CheckVersion();

        if(!check.isUpToDate)
        {
            // do something for update
            yield break;
        }

        // is up to date so start and wait for loading
        yield return loading.LoadAsyncOperation();

        // and so on
    }
}
```

And there are also some builtin ways for waiting like e.g. [WaitUntil](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html), [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) etc.

Comment: I made an edit, but it just occurred to me. All of these "yield return SomeMethod()" calls must be "yield return StartCoroutine(SomeMethod());" Additionally, the first two methods are voids. Coroutines must be IEnumerators. Just a note.

Comment: @Asyranok if yielding IEnumerators you don't have to /can't use `StartCoroutine` it is rather all handled by the one main Coroutine

Comment: Really? Did that change? I have yeild returned Coroutines without it by accident, and the code simply doesn't run. It always ignores if I do not wrap it in StartCoroutine, and simply doesn't error on compile or execution. Spent many hours debugging an issue where the code just wasn't running for this reason. Granted, I may be using an older Unity?

Comment: Or, you mean that the one Coroutine does not need StartCoroutine. It is inferred as a Coroutine? What about the void methods being "yield return"ed?

Comment: Ofcourse they all have to be IEnumerators ;) I added this as comment. I thought it was clear already saying `You can simply yield other IEnumerators`

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.